# I need to apply multiple equations on a pandas column based on certain criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe which requires multiple equations based on certain criteria. I need to take the first 3 letters of an identifier, then, if it is True, I need to divide the value associated with that row by a certain amount.

The dataframe is as follows:

```
ID     Value
US123  10000
US121  10000
MX122  10000
MX125  10000
BR123  10000
BR127  10000
```

I need to divide the value by 100 if the ID starts with 'MX', and divide the value by 1000 if the ID starts with 'BR'.  All other values need to remain the same.
I also do not want to create a new filtered dataframe.  I have had success filtering by ID then doing the logic checks, but I need to apply it over a much larger frame.

This is the code I am using for the filtered frame.

```
filtered['Value'] = np.where(filtered.ID.apply(lambda x: x[:3]).isin(['MX']) == True, filtered.Value/100, filtered.Value/1000)
```

I've also tried df.loc but I cannot figure out how to apply the changes to the dataframe, it seems to only show me a series of data but not apply it to the DF.

That code is here:

```
df.loc[(df['ID'].str.contains("MX") == True), 'Value']/100
df.loc[(df['ID'].str.contains("BR") == True), 'Value']/1000
```

Is there any better way to do this?  How can I apply the changes using df.loc to the main dataframe rather than have it appear in a series?

The desired output should be:

```
ID     Value
US123  10000
US121  10000
MX122  100
MX125  100
BR123  10
BR127  10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After computing the divided values using `.loc`, it must be re-assigned back to the `DF` used to make the selection as the operation is not inplace by itself.

Use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to check for string starting with a given pattern.

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.startswith('MX'), 'Value'] /= 100
df.loc[df['ID'].str.startswith('BR'), 'Value'] /= 1000
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)
df
```

[image]

Comment: This works, interesting thanks very much!  The /= part is kind of confusing as to why the division sign would be before the = sign.

Comment: It's similar to the C _increment_ / _decrement_ (++/--)operators, but Python instead of incrementing/decrementing the value re-assigns the incremented/decremented value back to the variable. Eg:- `var += 1` is a more succint form of writing  the more verbose `var = var + 1`. Same case with division/multiplication too.